# JavaScript regular expression to remember last bracket type encountered

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-operator

In JavaScript want to be able to match text that is:

- `(`surrounded by parentheses`)`
- `[`surrounded by square brackets`]`
- not surrounded by either type of bracket

In the following expression...

```
none[square](round)(accept]able)[wrong).text
```

... there should be 4 matches, for `none`, `[square]`, `(round)` and `(accept]able)`. However `[wrong)` should not match because there is no closing `]` to be found.

In [my best attempt so far](https://regex101.com/r/mV6gD2/1)...

```
([([])[A-Za-z]+[\])]|[^\[()\]]+
```

... `(accept]`, `able` and `[wrong)` are incorrectly matched, while `(accept]able)` as a whole is not matched. I'm not too concerned about `(accept]able)`; I would prefer no match at all to a match with imbalanced brackets.

I am guessing that I need to replace the `[\])]` expression with one that  checks the value of the initial matching group, and uses `)` if the first match was `(` or `]` if the first match was `[`.

I have tried working with [conditional expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). These seem to work well in PCRE and Python, but [not in JavaScript](https://regex101.com/r/cM0cO8/1).

Is this a problem that can be solved in a JavaScript regular expression on its own, or will I have to handle this piecemeal in a bulky JavaScript function?

Comment: is `[abc)def]` allowed?

Comment: Chunks like `[abc)def]`, `(abc]def)`, `[abc(def]` and `(abc]def)` should either all fail or all be accepted in their entirety. I don't mind which. I am hoping that users will never attempt such aberrations.

Comment: Don't hope anything from users.

Comment: Sure. I'll just be happy to make their experience predictable :)

Comment: Nice question. That's a pretty difficult regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that consists to match the two cases (acceptable and non-acceptable) and to separate the results in two different capture groups. So whatever you need to do with the results you only have to test which group succeeds:

```
/(\[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\)|[a-z]+)|([\[(][\s\S]*?(?:[\])]|$))/gi
```

pattern details:

```
(  # acceptable capture group
    \[ [^\]]* \]
  |
    \( [^)]* \)
  |
    [a-z]+
)
|
(  # non-acceptable capture group
    [\[(] [\s\S]*? (?: [\])] | $ ) # unclosed parens
)
```

This pattern doesn't care if a square bracket is enclosed between round brackets and vice-versa, but you can easily be more constrictive with this pattern that forbids any other brackets between brackets (square or round):

```
(  # acceptable capture group
    \[ [^()\[\]]* \]
  |
    \( [^()\[\]]* \)
  |
    [a-z]+
)
|
(  # non-acceptable capture group
    [\[(] [\s\S]*? (?: [\])] | $ ) # unclosed parens
)
```

Note about these two patterns: You can choose the default behavior when a unclosed bracket is found. The two patterns are designed to stop the non-acceptable part at the first closing bracket or if not found at the end of the string, but you can change this behavior and choose that an unclosing bracket stops always at the end of the string like this: `[\[(][\s\S]*$`

Comment: Merci! Un grand gloubi-boulga sera livré prochainement. This has given me a good starting point. I'll need to treat other edge cases like `[no(yes)ok` which don't match nicely yet, but now I have a new way to think about this. Thank you.

Comment: We look forward to it! For edge cases, all you need is to choose the default behavior, after it is easy to write the pattern for non-acceptable cases. (in other words, describe all what you want to avoid (until the last character) in the non-acceptable group)

Comment: Here's what I ended up using: https://regex101.com/r/uW1dV5/1 This is for an interactive story-telling activity. Readers pick up tokens according to the path they follow through the story, and certain tokens enable buttons [], or show the button in a disabled state (). My test string says: "If you have less than 3 active tokens or exactly 23 alternative tokens, then this PNG image will appear as a button. If you have more than 4 disabled tokens or no notEnabled tokens, the button will appear but not be active." Now to create the authoring tool that will generate this automatically : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I get all of the possible strings, but maybe this does the trick?

```
/\[([A-Za-z]*)\]|\(([\]A-Za-z]*)\)/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
/^(\[[^\[]+?\]|\([^\(]+?\)|[^\[\(]+)$/gm
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mV6gD2/2)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
\((\w*\s*)\)|\[(\w*)\]|\((\w*\s*|\])*\)|\((\w*\s*|\[)*\)|\[(\w*\s*|\()*\]|\[(\w*\s*|\))*\]|^\b\w*\s*\b
```

Demo here:

https://regex101.com/r/mV6gD2/2